# Use cloned VLCJ in multiple windows

Tags: java, swing, vlc, libvlc, vlcj

I want to have two copies of same video in two different JFrames! 
At the moment I have achieved that 2 videos is displaying but only one is "integrated" into a JFrame. As far as I've read it's not fully developed to be integrated with all copies.. Am I wrong in this? Also is there any other way to achieve what I want?

This is my code playing stuff in 2 JFrames and also a JFileChooser for simplicity.

```
public class MyMultiDisplay
{
    List <String> argsList;
    MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory;
    EmbeddedMediaPlayer player;
    JFrame frame1;
    JFrame frame2;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new NativeDiscovery().discover();

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new MyStart();
            }
        });
    }

    public MyMultiDisplay()
    {
        frame1 = new JFrame("My First Media Player");
        frame1.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 400);
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame2 = new JFrame("My Second Media Player");
        frame2.setBounds(700, 500, 600, 400);
        frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        argsList = new ArrayList <String>();
        argsList.add("--video-splitter=clone");
        argsList.add("--clone-count=2");
        mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory(argsList);
        player = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        player.setVideoSurface(mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(canvas));
        frame1.add(canvas);
        frame1.setVisible(true);
        frame2.setVisible(true);
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            player.playMedia(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I want to have two copies of same video in two different JFrames!"* ...why?

Comment: It was meant as an example! The real use will be like PowerPoint but for video integrated within my own program. One video display per screen.

Comment: *"One video display per screen."* Why would the user want two versions of the same video on-screen at once? I'm not saying there are no reasons for it, I'm curious as to what the reason is in this case.

Comment: One miniature where the operator can control the video and one fullscreen meant for public display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost a year later I decided that for completeness i'll post my final solution here if anyone else ever find their way here!

I created a library project using VLCJ as base able to in a really easy way use the DirektMediaPlayer to play the same video to multiple frames/windows/surfaces/JComponents/whatever in a really simple manner. It is not that resource heavy either in my unexperienced experience. 100 windows at the same time playing the same video and still no lag!

Feel free to check it out!

https://github.com/APayerl/VlcjWind

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done.

The LibVLC API, and therefore vlcj, does not support passing more than one native window ID for embedding purposes.

Comment: Would it be possible to use a DirectMediaPlayer (I think it was called that?) and then have two surfaces paint from the same buffer?

Comment: That would probably work, but performance would take a hit and you'd have the other limitations around direct media player (like resize limitations) - the native embedded way is always the preferred way IMHO.

Comment: well if that is the only way for my needs then I see not that many alternatives unfortunatly... : /